# MBProgressHUD not disappearing after calling hide

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am sure this is an issue with my iOS/ObjC noob-ness...

I have a UITableView with entries in, when the user selects a row,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
   [self.twitter sendUpdate:[self getTweet]];
```

and

```
- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)text;
{
    NSLog(@"showing HUD");
    self.progressSheet = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] animated:YES];
    self.progressSheet.labelText = @"Working:";
    self.progressSheet.detailsLabelText = text;

    // Build a twitter request
    TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] 
                                                 parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:text 
                                                                                        forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

    // Post the request
    [postRequest setAccount:self.twitterAccount];

    // Block handler to manage the response
    [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
     {
         NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);

           NSLog(@"hiding HUD");
           [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] animated:YES];
           self.progressSheet = nil;
```

It calls the builtin Twitter api to send a tweet. I am using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) while the sending is going on. I am getting erratic behaviour with the HUD disappearance, generally it hangs around 10 or so seconds longer than it should. Based on the show/hide logging I am seeing.

I have another, simpler view, which just lists tweets and that uses the HUD with no problem - although its done via the viewWillAppear call.

Perhaps I need to do the showing via another thread?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts  ~chris

Comment: Why attach your HUD to the window? Makes more sense to attach it to your view. Also, then instead of using hideHUDforView method why not just call hide:animated on your propertySheet HUD that you already have a reference to? That makes help.

Comment: Thanks - as its in some common code, I was avoiding passing the view around.  I had tried that, but did not help.  Just tried switching to using the hide: call, but no better either. I am doing some GC calls later in the didSelectRow call, but adding some logging shows thats not the hold up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems my issue is that I was trying to close the HUD on a thread other than the main one.

Using the trick in one of the answers to this question, its now working a lot better.

[GCD to perform task in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662360/gcd-to-perform-task-in-main-thread)

Namely, using the method defined "runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking"

The close dialog code is now like this:

```
runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(^{
    NSLog(@"hiding HUD/mainthread");
    [self.progressSheet hide:YES];
    self.progressSheet = nil;
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you are right about ui thread.
You can also write this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self.progressSheet hide:YES];
  self.progressSheet = nil;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this method for showing the HUD:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.labelText = @"Working";
```

Instead of:

```
self.progressSheet = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] animated:YES];
self.progressSheet.labelText = @"Working:";
self.progressSheet.detailsLabelText = text;
```

And this for hiding it:

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Instead of:

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried that unsuccessfully. I seem to have fixed it by hiding the HUD on the "main thread" - see my answer below.