# How to debug current queue in dispatch_async?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

This is what I met in one of the projects:

```
private func updateBadgeView() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0 {

            self.newMessagesBadgeView.hidden = false
            self.newMessagesCountLabel.text = String(UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber)

        } else {
            self.newMessagesBadgeView.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

And I suppose that `dispatch_async` with that queue is useless here. How can I check the queue here? Do I really need here this block? I need to check if it is the same queue as without block.

The above function is inside subclass of `UIViewController` and is called in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`

**UPDATE:**

I know that because of a bug in ios, it is needed here:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.presentOverlayController(selectViewController)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the method is already running on the main queue? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662360/gcd-to-perform-task-in-main-thread. But viewDidLoad etc *are* called on the main queue.

Comment: Weird, I never have to do this, what happens if you remove dispatch_async

Answer (score 1):

If it is called in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidApperar` is useless.
However you can check with a similar code:

```
private func updateBadgeView() {

    let block = {
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0 {

            self.newMessagesBadgeView.hidden = false
            self.newMessagesCountLabel.text = String(UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber)

        } else {
            self.newMessagesBadgeView.hidden = true
        }
    }

    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        block();
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        block();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: If I debug like you said, it is ok... in both cases (within block and without, there is a main thread). But this is the same for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. There is also main thread for both, but dispatch must be there to make it working?

Comment: I suppose that is using the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` not for switch between threads, but to run the code in the next event  in the event loop.
Sometimes is needed to handle with animations etc

Answer (score 0):

For sure `applicationIconBadgeNumber` is used in different queue. If you do not use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` you may observe delay while updating your `newMessagesCountLabel`.

You can use it with Swift 3 syntax now:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // your code
}
```