# Maintain main queue without deadlock in swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm converting one of my project from Objective C to swift. I was handling main queue synchronously without deadlock using following code

```
void runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(void (^block)(void))
```

How can I convert this method definition to swift. I'm new to swift, please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method *definition* is easy to convert:

```
func runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(block:()->()) {
    // ...
}
```

You could easily have found that out simply by looking at the "generated interface" for this method.

What the method actually *does*, however, I have no idea (because you have not shown it).

Comment: I was trying to implement http://stackoverflow.com/a/10341532/2594560 in my swift code.