# How to execute a function that has to run on main queue when main queue is paused?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

The function below checks whether protected data is available.

```
func isProtectedDataAvailable(_ completion: ((_ isProtectedDataAvailable: Bool)->Void)?) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion?(UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable)
    }
}
```

How can I change the function so that it can be called even when the main thread is paused in a setting like this:

```
let dispatch = DispatchGroup()

dispatch.enter()

isProtectedDataAvailable { isProtectedDataAvailable in
    //...
    dispatch.leave()
}

dispatch.wait()
```

The `wait()` above would pause the main queue and the completion handler would never be called.

Comment: You can't, that's how serial queues work. You can run the block in the background and use a semaphore or mutex, or maybe an NSRecursiveLock. This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/172958). If you give us a better idea of what exactly you need, maybe we can suggest how to use one.

Comment: @Kevin The idea is that the function should return whether protected data is available without the developer caring about the setting it is used in. The only alternative I see is to add to the docs that one must not block the main queue when calling this function.

Comment: Actually I think this is the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330679/how-to-dispatch-on-main-queue-synchronously-without-a-deadlock?rq=1

Comment: Yes, that would work.