# Perform UI Changes on main thread using dispatch_async or performSelectorOnMainThread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) vs. performSelector - need a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225130/grand-central-dispatch-gcd-vs-performselector-need-a-better-explanation)

To execute "stuff" on the main thread, should I use `dispatch_async` or `performSelectorOnMainThread`? Is there a preferred way, right/or wrong, and/or best practice?

Example: I'm performing some logic within the block of an `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest` method. Because I'm doing stuff to the main view such as presenting a `UIAlertView` I need to show the `UIAlertView` on the main thread. To do this I'm using the following code.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    // code snipped out to keep this question short

    if(![NSThread isMainThread]) 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Some Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];
        });
    }
}];
```

Within that same `if(![NSThread isMainThread])` statement I also call some custom methods. The question is, should I use the `dispatch_async` method that I'm using above or is it better to use `performSelectorOnMainThread` instead? For example, full code below:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    // code snipped out to keep this question short

    if(![NSThread isMainThread]) 
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Some Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];

            // call custom methods in dispatch_async?
            [self hideLoginSpinner];
        });

        // or call them here using performSelectorOnMainThread???
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideLoginSpinner) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}];
```

FYI - If I DO NOT perform these actions on he main thread I see a few second delay when presenting the `UIAlertView` and I receive the following message in the debugger `wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003`. I've learned that this is because you need to make changes to the UI on the main thread... In case someone is wondering why I'm doing what I'm doing...

Comment: closely related: [What's the difference between performSelectorOnMainThread: and dispatch_async() on main queue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335434/)

Comment: The most obvious difference from the POV of _writing_ the code is that dispatching a block is more flexible: it's way easier to handle primitive arguments, for example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in the links provided by Josh Caswell, the two are almost equivalent. The most notable differences is that `performSelectorOnMainThread` will only execute in the default run loop mode and will wait if the run loop is running in a tracking or other mode. However, there are some significant differences for writing and maintaining the code.

1. `dispatch_async` has the big advantage that the compiler does all its usual tests. If you mistype the method in `performSelectorOnMainThread` you fail at run time, rather than compile time.
2. `dispatch_async` makes it much easier to return data from the main thread using the `__block` qualifier.
3. `dispatch_async` makes it much easier to handle primitive arguments since you don't have to wrap them in an object. However, this comes with a potential pitfall. If you have a pointer to some data remember that block capture does not deep copy the data. On the other hand wrapping the data in an object as you would be forced to do for `performSelectorOnMainThread` does deep copy (unless you set special options). Without a deep copy you can run into intermittent bugs that are frustrating to debug. So this means you should wrap things like `char *` in `NSString` before you call `dispatch_async`.

Comment: 1. `performSelectorOnMainThread` now shows an undeclared-selector warning.

Comment: If you turn on the Undeclared Selector warning in Xcode build settings then you do get _some_ build time testing anytime @selector is used, including in `performSelectorOnMainThread`. This helps with typos, but be aware of this warning's limitations. It checks if any matching selector has been declared yet, not just those for the object you are calling `performSelectorOnMainThread` on. Second, this enforces a coding style convention that methods and selectors must be declared before being used.