# Downloading PDF In iOS App Freezes

Tags: ios, pdf, nsurlconnection

My app allows for downloading a PDF to the device.  However, while the PDF is being downloaded, the app is unable to do anything until the download completes.  How can I do this so other actions can be handled while download is in progress?  This is what I have so far for downloading it.

```
RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             NSString *urlString = entry.articlePDF;
             NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

             NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

             NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             NSString *filename = [entry.articleTitle stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"];
             NSString *removed = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
             NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

             NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: removed];
             NSLog(@"Downloadstarted%@", pdfPath);
             [data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: you are downloading the pdf as synchronous request so it will block that thread until all the data downloads from the server, instead of downloading it on main thread download it using asynchronous task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run it in a background thread, like that:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSString *urlString = entry.articlePDF;
         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *filename = [entry.articleTitle stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"];
         NSString *removed = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
         NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

         NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: removed];
         NSLog(@"Downloadstarted%@", pdfPath);
         [data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
    })
```

Comment: Perfect!  Is there a notifier for when a file has finished writing to path?

Comment: after the line '[data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];' the file has finished. If you want to notify the UI, do a dispatch inside of the main thread. Take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530050/perform-ui-changes-on-main-thread-using-dispatch-async-or-performselectoronmaint

Comment: Please use `NSURLConnection` directly, with its dedicated **asynchronous** API, rather than kludging together a background synchronous operation like this. Also there is no benefit here to using `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`

Answer (score -1):

Use ASIHTTPRequest for download

```
self.request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:pdflinkURL];
[self.request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestedPDFFinished:)];
[self.request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestedPDFFailed:)];
[self.request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
self.request.delegate = self;
[self.request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
[self.request startAsynchronous];

- (void)requestedPDFFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req
{
    NSData *recievedData = [req responseData];
    // Save top Document Directory
}
//sagar change
- (void)requestedPDFFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req
{
    NSLog(@"%@",req.error);
}
```