# Hiding/showing a particular `UIView`

Tags: ios, uiview

I have around 5 `UIViews`in my .xib, inially i am showing only 1 `view(view1)` which has some `labels` and `button`, when i click on button i prompt a systems `alertView` for granting permission from the setting of the phone and once i get the permission, i am hiding `view1` and showing other 4 `views` using `setHidden` method, but the `view` is not refreshing and not showing other 4 `views`.

```
-(void) gotPermission 
{ 
    [self->_View2 setHidden:NO]; 
    [self->_View3 setHidden:NO]; 
    [self->_View4 setHidden:NO]; 
    [self->_View1 setHidden:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: hide view1 to be able to show other views.....

Comment: You need to to send the view1 to back using the method sendSubviewToBack: may be this one is the issue.

Comment: -(void) gotPermission
{
    [self->_View2 setHidden:NO];
    [self->_View3 setHidden:NO];
    [self->_View4 setHidden:NO];
    [self->_View1 setHidden:YES];
}

I am calling this `gotPermission` method when user clicks on `ok`

Comment: @PareshNavadiya, it wont work as other views are also still hidden.

Comment: @BKjadav lemme try it once as you said.

Comment: are you forcing the view to upload with something like "[self.view setNeedsDisplay]" after you call the gotPermission method?

Comment: @VaroX Yes i tried that too... but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Check for proper connections to the properties, (ie view1 with the view1 in the storyboard or XIB).

```
-(void)gotPermission{
 self.View2.hidden = NO;
 self.View3.hidden = NO;
 self.View4.hidden = NO;
 self.View1.hidden = YES;
}
```

Check if views are overlapping on one another, If not check if views are inside one another, if so, all the views should have a similar parent view (eg. self.view)

Comment: I tried but its not working, still stays on the same `view1`

Comment: are any of your views inside one another? does all the views have a particular view as their parent?

Comment: Yes all the views has only one parent view.

Comment: Are all these inside a tableview?

Comment: no, there a parent view which 4 view and each view has like
view1->view and button
view2->tableview
view3->toolbar

Comment: can u plz post the picture of the xib or the view controller?

Comment: Hi, it seems that it is hiding the `view` and showing another `view` but taking time because of `requestAccessToEntityType for calendar`. Do you why its happening? I mean when i grant the permission the view which should be shown comes very late.

Comment: If you can post a bit more code, i can understand what exactly is going wrong!

Comment: When user clicks on a button i call this method `[[CalendarEH sharedInstance] requestPermissionWithEventStore];`

then this block is called
[self->_sharedEventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {  Which gives error as `Error getting all calendars: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)`

Comment: I got the answer, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530050/perform-ui-changes-on-main-thread-using-dispatch-async-or-performselectoronmaint

Comment: Basicallly need to call the method with the use of main thread, which brings the subview to front instantly.